# Jquery - Focus on an input field in a form on pageload?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to focus on the username input in my login screen to allow for easier access to logging in and currently my jquery looks like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#Username').focus();
});
```

but that doesn't work... any ideas?

Comment: Post the <input> tag for your username form item.

Comment: like most people have already said, that should work unless your naming of that username tag is incorrect

Comment: this is doing asp.net MVC, inspecting the element in the page verifies my ID is correct, the code is <%= Html.TextBox("Username") %>

Comment: the errors im getting in Ie are object expected

Comment: Make sure jQuery is referenced and loaded. Object expected likely means $ (which is an alias for jQuery) can't be found.

Comment: jquery is referenced and working... I have it zebra striping tables and doing some other functions.. not sure why it isn't focusing on the input

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It does work in the following simple example. Therefore there is something else going on on your page that causes the input to lose focus. I suggest using setTimeout to set the focus.

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
    <title>test!</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#Username').focus();
});
    </script>

  </head>

  <body>
  <input id="Username" />
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5):

Does the  tag have an id attribute?

```
<input id="Username" name="Username" type="text" />
```

I'm guessing it only has a name attribute:

```
<input name="Username" type="text" />
```

If you can't add the ID attribute, you can select it like this:

```
$("input[name='Username']").focus();
```

Answer (score 3):

A timeout will probably do the trick:

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
        setTimeout(function(){
            $("input[name='inputname']").focus();
        }, 200);
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, that is how you do it.  Make sure the ID is correct, I suppose.

Answer (score 1):

Internet Explorer got some problems with for example this code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        //focus on search field
        $("#userSearchField").focus();
});
```

How stupid it looks, but this solved the problem for me:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //focus on search field
    $("#userSearchField").focus();
    $("#userSearchField").focus();
});
```

Or try to use  `setTimeout`

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML looks like <input id="Username" ...> (Case-sensitive)?